Настройка языка в mediawiki
Установил движок MediaWiki и несколько плагинов к нему. Но эти плагины почему-то не подгружают языки, на которые они переведены. В итоге получаю сообщения вида ⧼visualeditor-ca-editsource⧽ вместо перевода.
В LocalSettings.php указано: $wgLanguageCode = "ru";. Json'ы c переводами соответствующих строк у плагинов присутствуют. В чём может быть проблема?

Попытайтесь выполнить скрипт php maintenance/run.php rebuildLocalisationCache. Он обновит кэш локализации. Кроме того, проверьте значения переменных $wgLocalisationCacheConf и $wgCacheDirectory.

Благодарю! Разкомментировал $wgCacheDirectory и всё заработало. Хотя я так и не понял, почему по-умолчанию оно закомментировано, если без него получаются такие проблемы
